# Ruby: Improve complex initialize method

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have a piece of Ruby code that boils down to this:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :a, :b, :c
  def initialize
    build_a
    build_b
    build_c
  end

  private

  def build_a
    # something complex that eventually results in @a = something
  end
  def build_b
    # something complex that eventually results in @b = something
  end
  def build_c
    # something complex that eventually results in @c = something
  end
end
```

Calling `build_*` in the `initialize` method seems a bit superfluous. Is there a better way to write this? Of course I'm aware of the lazy loading pattern:

```
class A
  def a
    @a ||= something_complex
  end
end
```

But, I need this code to be thread safe, so I can't use that pattern here.

Edit: My main concern with this code, is that I would like to see the fact that `build_a` should be called after initialisation, written at the definition of `build_a` instead of in the `initialize` method.

Answer (score 1):

For now I went with

```
require 'active_support/callbacks'

class Foo
  include ActiveSupport::Callbacks
  define_callbacks :initialize

  attr_reader :a, :b, :c

  def initialize
    run_callbacks :initialize do
      # do the rest of initialize
    end
  end

  protected

  def build_a
    # something complex that eventually results in @a = something
  end
  set_callback :initialize, :after, :build_a

  def build_b
    # something complex that eventually results in @b = something
  end
  set_callback :initialize, :after, :build_b

  def build_c
    # something complex that eventually results in @c = something
  end
  set_callback :initialize, :after, :build_c
end
```

I'm not 100% sure I like this solution, but it works.

Edit: After some thinking and playing with Piotr Kruczek's solution, I went with this:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    protected_methods.grep(/^initialize_/).each do |method|
      send(method)
    end
  end

  protected

  def initialize_a
    # something complex that eventually results in @a = something
  end

  def initialize_b
    # something complex that eventually results in @b = something
  end

  def initialize_c
    # something complex that eventually results in @c = something
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Those callbacks will be a real pain in the ass to test and maintain. Wouldn't this solution be better?:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :a, :b, :c

  def initialize
    # things that belong in initialize
  end

  def self.call # or any other name
    new.build_things
  end

  def build_things
    build_a
    build_b
    build_c
  end
end
```

The only drawback is that you would use `Foo.call` instead of `Foo.new`. If you don't want to this class to 'feel' like a service object, I'd go ahead and wrap it in one, like `FooBuilder`. This way you avoid callbacks, testing is easy and your code clean and readable. I think it's the best approach if you want to `build_things` after initialization.

Comment: Hmm, I like the idea of putting this list of builders inside another method, but I don't think it solves the main concern: this list of methods that are called. Maybe I'll try to implement a loop that calls all the `build_*` methods, or something like that.